# Why isn't my body and footer not properly applying in its position?

Tags: html, css

Note: This is a testing website meaning that this website is only created to expand my knowledge in html and css and will not be published.

Hello! I am currently working on one of my personal projects. I ran into a problem in where my body seems to have condense itself around the header (in which you will see the block of white space) instead of being a body to the website. The same will go with the footer in which it is not applying as it should be. Usually I would have gotten the problem solved but it seems like I am unable to find the solution to it. Can I get a brief knowledge of what went wrong?

```
<header>
<h1 id="page_name"> Humble Forest Preserve</h1>
<nav>
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li> <a href="Forest_preserve_main.html" id="nav">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="humble_forest_about_us.html" id="nav">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href="humble_forest_volunteer.html" id="nav">Volunteer</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" id="nav">Rentals</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" id="nav">News</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" id="nav">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
<body>
<div class="colmask threecol">
    <div class="colmid">
        <div class="colleft">
            <div class="col1">
         <img src="our_mission_pic.jpg" alt="#" id="imagecoloum"> <h2 id="h2styles">Our Mission</h2>
            <p id="rightp1">In order to keep the forest clean and safe for both
                members and animals,<br /> we push push ourselves using these 
                objectives.</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
            <img src="board_meeting_pic.jpg" alt="#" id="imagecoloum2"><h2 id="h2styles">Board Meetings</h2>
            <p>Information on the Forest Preserve of Austin County Board of Commissioners,<br /> board meetings and more.</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="colmask threecol">
    <div class="colmid">
        <div class="colleft">
            <div class="col1">
            <img src="forest_history.jpg" alt="#" id="imagecoloum3"><h2 id="h2styles">History</h2>
            <p>There are plenty of historical landmarks within the forest preserve. Rather
            if you <br /> like to read the information  while in the forest preserve or
            learn it from our website,<br /> we can help.</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
            <img src="foi_img.jpg" alt="#" id="imagecoloum4"><h2 id="h2styles">Freedom of Information Act</h2>
            <p>Members of the public may make requests for inspection or for copies of
                public records <br /> for the FPDCC under the Texas Freedom of Information Act
                (“FOIA”).</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
            <ul class="fright"
       <li class="ftitle">Learn more</li>
       <li class="fcol"> <a href="Forest_preserve_main.html">Humble Forest Preserve.com</li>
       <li class="fcol"> <a href="">About us</li>
    </ul>

</footer>
```

```
/*Html styles*/
html {
background-image: url("green-fade-background.gif");
background-size: cover;
}


/*Body Styles */
body {
background-color: white;
margin-left: 200px;
padding: 25px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

/*Title and styles*/
h1#page_name {
text-align: center;
width: 80%;
height: 60px;
background-color: rgb(86, 160, 33);

}

/* common column settings */
.colleft,
.colmid,
.colright {
float:left;
width:100;
position:relative;
}

.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {
float:left;
position:relative;
padding:0 0 1em 0;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left: 60px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

ul#fright {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
}

li.fcol {
background: green;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}


 /*Horizontal Navigation Styles */
 ul#navigation {
 background-color: rgb(86, 160, 33);
 width: 80%;
 }

 li#nav {
 width: 80px;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: rgb(86, 160, 33)
 }

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: none
}


li {
float: left;
width: 20%;
}


li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
background-color: rgb(23, 80, 7);
}

/* Footer style and background */ 
footer {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(86, 160, 33);
color: black;
font-size: 20px;
}

ul#mediaicons {
float: right;
width: 25%;
height: 50%;
}

/* Partnership images and logos placements */

section#partnershiplogo {
float: right;
}

img#partnershipimages {
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin: 40px;
hspace: 5px;
}
 li#partnershipimages {
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 }

/*Button Style and Control */
button {
background-color: #4CAF50;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, just scanning this right off the bat, I see a header section outside of the body. All of your visible page content should be nested in the body tag. The body tag means something different than the body of your page content, it's more like the "body" of the html message.

Comment: @Oswalt I have tried moving the body tag above the header but seems like nothing happened.Thanks for that input though.

Comment: There are some other things going on with the html, there are some missing endtags and unterminated tags, and moving the body tag so that it wraps the entire thing will cause the structure to change a little. I'd say first, try an editor that has syntax highlighting. This will help point out syntax errors quickly. Two on the web that could help are jsfiddle.net or codepen.io.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several errors like ending HTML tags, the header outside the body, and several CSS errors in witch I fixed.  I would compare the 2 to see what was changed due to the fact that there were a lot to list and wasn't really efficient to list all of them.

```css
/*Html styles*/
html {
background-image: url("green-fade-background.gif");
background-size: cover;
}


/*Body Styles */
body {
background-color: white;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

/*Title and styles*/
h1#page_name {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: rgb(86, 160, 33);

}

/* common column settings */
.colleft,
.colmid,
.colright {
float:left;
width:100%;
position:relative;
}

.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {
float:left;
position:relative;
padding:0 0 1em 0;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left: 60px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

ul#fright {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
}

li.fcol {
background: green;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}


 /*Horizontal Navigation Styles */
 ul#navigation {
 background-color: rgb(86, 160, 33);
 width: 100%;
 }

 li#nav {
 width: 80px;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: rgb(86, 160, 33)
 }

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: none
}


li {
float: left;
width: 20%;
}


li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
background-color: rgb(23, 80, 7);
}

/* Footer style and background */ 
footer {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(86, 160, 33);
color: black;
font-size: 20px;
}

ul#mediaicons {
float: right;
width: 25%;
height: 50%;
}

/* Partnership images and logos placements */

section#partnershiplogo {
float: right;
}

img#partnershipimages {
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin: 40px;
hspace: 5px;
}
 li#partnershipimages {
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 }

/*Button Style and Control */
button {
background-color: #4CAF50;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
<h1 id="page_name"> Humble Forest Preserve</h1>
<nav>
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li> <a href="Forest_preserve_main.html" id="nav">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="humble_forest_about_us.html" id="nav">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href="humble_forest_volunteer.html" id="nav">Volunteer</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" id="nav">Rentals</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" id="nav">News</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" id="nav">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
<div class="colmask threecol">
    <div class="colmid">
        <div class="colleft">
            <div class="col1">
         <img src="our_mission_pic.jpg" alt="#" id="imagecoloum"> <h2 id="h2styles">Our Mission</h2>
            <p id="rightp1">In order to keep the forest clean and safe for both
                members and animals,<br /> we push push ourselves using these 
                objectives.</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
            <img src="board_meeting_pic.jpg" alt="#" id="imagecoloum2"><h2 id="h2styles">Board Meetings</h2>
            <p>Information on the Forest Preserve of Austin County Board of Commissioners,<br /> board meetings and more.</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="colmask threecol">
    <div class="colmid">
        <div class="colleft">
            <div class="col1">
            <img src="forest_history.jpg" alt="#" id="imagecoloum3"><h2 id="h2styles">History</h2>
            <p>There are plenty of historical landmarks within the forest preserve. Rather
            if you <br /> like to read the information  while in the forest preserve or
            learn it from our website,<br /> we can help.</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
            <img src="foi_img.jpg" alt="#" id="imagecoloum4"><h2 id="h2styles">Freedom of Information Act</h2>
            <p>Members of the public may make requests for inspection or for copies of
                public records <br /> for the FPDCC under the Texas Freedom of Information Act
                (“FOIA”).</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
            <ul class="fright">
       <li class="ftitle">Learn more</li>
       <li class="fcol"> <a href="Forest_preserve_main.html">Humble Forest Preserve.com</a></li>
       <li class="fcol"> <a href="">About us</a></li>
    </ul>

</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! you definitely help solved my issue!

Comment: No problem glad I could help